# How different digital certificate work or communicate?

Tags: security, digital-certificate

I am working in a telecom based intranet application which uses its own enterprise digital certificate. However there are new changes introduced which require 3rd party drivers which have their own 3rd party digital certificate.

My question is how handshaking is done between 2 different digital certificates?
Do we need to check the validation of the digital certificate of the incoming new drivers programatically?

Comment: Please read [tour] then [ask] then edit your question to include more details so it's something we can answer.   A code signing certificate is used to show who created that content.  We have no idea what your application needs to do with the information or how and when it must be verified.

Comment: Sorry for not able to pharse my query properly..All i want to know is whether there will be any issues happening between communication with different drivers running in different digital certificates.?

Comment: We don't know.  That depends on your operating system, security software running, and anything your own application does to enforce security.  For a Windows application, most drivers are signed by the hardware vendor not Microsoft so having many different certificates is normal.  This link explaining what signing is might help - https://www.sslshopper.com/what-is-code-signing.html